# Poisson distribution with $E(X^2) = 12.$

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

I tried to resolve this issue, but I don’t know if it’s correct, could anyone appreciate the resolution and help me?

The emission of a radioactive source is such that the number of particles emitted in a
time period, given in seconds, $X$, has Poisson distribution with $E[X^2] = 12.$
observed the issue during that period, what is the probability to be issued $4$ or
more particles?

The key is that is that the mean and variance of a Poisson distribution are both equal to λ. In particular
$\lambda=\text{Var}(X)=E[X^2]-(EX)^2=12-\lambda^2\iff\lambda^2+\lambda-12=0 \quad (\lambda>0)$

We have $\lambda = 3$
\begin{align*}
  P(X=x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}.\lambda^{x}}{x!} \Rightarrow P(X\geq 4)&= 1-P(X<4)\\ 
  &=1-\left[\frac{e^{-3}\cdot 3^{0}}{0!}+\frac{e^{-3}\cdot 3^{1}}{1!}+\frac{e^{-3}\cdot 3^{2}}{2!}+\frac{e^{-3}\cdot 3^{3}}{3!}\right]\\ 
  &= 1-[e^{-3}\cdot13]\\ 
  &=1-0,6472\\
  &=0,3528. 
\end{align*}

Thanks!

Comment: Two questions: 1) how did you find $\lambda$? , 2) Why did not you include the probability that $X=5$, $X=6$, etc?

Comment: I edited the post, could you check?

Comment: It is clear how you found $\lambda$ now. But you have to consider the whole series of probabilities $P(X=n)$ with $n\ge 4$ (better using the complement, check my answer)

Comment: Ok! Thank you for the appreciation! Now I will continue.

Comment: @GReyes, could you check if it’s correct now?

Comment: Yes, it is correct now.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @GReyes Can you help-me in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4053396/function-density

Answer (score 1):

Since $Var(X)=\lambda=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2=E[X^2]-\lambda^2$ you get the quadratic equation $\lambda^2+\lambda-12=0$ hence $\lambda=-4$ or $\lambda=3$, therefore $\lambda=3$. Then
$$
P(X\ge 4)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2)-P(X=3),
$$
which you easily compute with the pmf.